# Split strings in a multi-item list while keeping items together

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists:

```
[['w1 a b c'], ['w2 d e f g h i'], ['w3 j k l m n o p q', 'w5 r s t u v w x']...]
```

I want to split by space, but keeping w3 and w5 item together:

```
for i in listoflists:
    for j in i:
        j.split(' ')

[['w1', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['w2', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
['w3', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q']
['w5', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']...]
```

the desired output would be:

```
[['w1', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['w2', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
[['w3', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'], ['w5', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']]...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
result=[]
for i in listoflists:
    if len(i)==1:
        result.append(i[0].split(' '))
    else:
        result.append([k.split(' ') for k in i])

>>>print(result)

[['w1', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['w2', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], [['w3', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'], ['w5', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
out = [
    [y.split(' ') for y in x] if len(x) > 1 else x.pop().split(' ')
    for x in listoflists
]
```

Output

```
[print(a) for a in out]

['w1', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['w2', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
[['w3', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'], ['w5', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, and may be better in some cases than the IoaTzimas' answer, but it does create a single item nested list for the the first two items.